# call ssrs report using ssis 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-2012, exec

I've  created a report with ssrs. I'm wondering if there is any possibility to call the report (Excel format) using ssis and how to make it. My objectif is to execute all my ssis packages (ETL and reporting) in a row using a batch file. As an output, I get my report in Excel format.

Comment: If you rephrase your question, [how can I make SSRS export to Excel](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=how+can+I+make+ssrs+export+to+excel&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), what approach do you see people using? Incorporate the same logic into an SSIS package

Comment: how can I execute SSRS report and export it to Excel using SSIS package?

Comment: Why don't you just connect to the database that your report is calling using SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by installing a report generator task from codeplex website. it's an SSIS component which renders remote reports from sssrs and show them during execution.